# Snackbar appears behind keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar, snackbar

On newer Android versions, above 4.4, the SnackBar does not appear when the Soft Keyboard is visible.

My activity has `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`, so its size is being adjusted whenever the keyboard is shown.

However, when the keyboard is closed the SnackBar appears correctly at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Just to add that on Android 4.4 this works perfectly and the SnackBar is shown on top of the keyboard.